# How to get variable values from main and send them to a function?

Tags: c++, function

I have encountered a problem while running this code in my IDE.  You can see very early on that I've attempted to use a function.  The reason for this is to save memory later on by outputting text, but the problem occurs with the variables in the function.  The classType variable is uninitialized, how do I prevent this?  I have defined them in main, but when I try to output the text with the variables from main then it doesn't work properly.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string getName()
{
    string charName;
    int classType;
    cout << "What is your " << classType << "'s name?" << endl;
    cin >> charName;
    return charName;
}
int main()
{
    int classType; //Later we will ask the user what class they're playing.  
    string charName; 
    /*We will use a function to ask a question.  
    We use a function to save memory instead of copy-pasting the text*/
    cout <<"Welcome to \"Orcs and Ogres\"" << endl;
    cout << "What class do you want to play?  " << endl;
    cout << "\tType 1 for Warrior class]" << endl;
    cout << "\tType 2 for Archer class ]" << endl;
    cout << "\tType 3 for Mage class   ]" << endl;
    cin >> classType;
    if(classType == 1)
    {
        cout << endl << "You are a warrior" << endl;
        string classType;
        classType = "warrior";
        getName();
    }
    else if(classType == 2)
    {
        cout << endl << "You are an archer" << endl;
        string classType;
        classType = "archer";
        getName();
    }
    else if(classType == 3)
    {
        cout << endl << "You are a mage" << endl;
        string classType;
        classType = "mage";
        getName();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "UserError:  Number too high or too low";
    }
}
```

On the lines of code that use getName(), it outputs something like "What is your ***blank***'s name?"  instead of the proper classType.  I want to know how I can send variable values to a function from main so that it outputs text properly here.

Comment: Don't post links to code but post the code.

Comment: You didn't even read it then.

Comment: Stackoverflow is telling me my code is improperly formatted again, so if you could show me what I'm formatting wrong for future reference that's also helpful. I have a shareable link so that you can view the code here:"""

Comment: @NateDukes, highlight and press ctrl+k

Comment: Yep, duh.  I know.

Comment: Done, no problem for me.

Comment: `getName()::classType` is not the same object as `main()::classType`. In the former, you're printing an uninitialised variable. What did you expect to happen? Nothing good will, because it's undefined behaviour and thus renders your entire program ill-formed. If you want to pass a variable between functions... then sure, just _pass it_. (Or if you're trying to make it a global variable, A: don't and B: you're doing it wrong.)

Comment: Roughly the policy here is : no links to stuff you can post directly in the question.

Comment: That helps me get the code there but doesn't help me format for the future.  Whenever I ctrl+K I copy paste my code into the box, and it only includes the first line of code, then I ctrl+K again and it doesn't place a large grey box around all the code, instead it just highlights the text.

Comment: @NateDukes, copy it into the post, highlight **all** of the code, then press ctrl+k. I've done it for 2 years now, and it works

Comment: @NateDukes no idea what you have done, I copied the code you posted in the link, then I pasted it into the question, then I highlighted the pasted code, pressed Ctrl+K and that's it.

Comment: for emphasis re your edit: _"The classType variable is uninitialized, how do I prevent this?"_ You prevent it by knowing the fundamentals of how to pass variables between functions. Not knowing that indicates you need to read a book or tutorial; it doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: _/*We will use a function to ask a question. We use a function to save memory instead of copy-pasting the text*/_ Note that when writing a function you are not "saving memory": you avoiding code duplication, which is always a good thing. when we talk about "saving memory", we usually refer to save memory used at runtime. writing a function instead of duplicating code is a very different concept

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is because your getName function has no knowledge of whats stored in the classType variable. Read on how function variable scope works to understand the whole mechanism works might be beneficial.

If you wish to keep the current implementation of your program. Re-write your getName function to accept the string class as a parameter

```
string getName(string classType)
{
  string charName;
  cout << "What is your " << classType << "'s name?" << endl;
  cin >> charName;
  return charName;
}
```

and in your main you'd call the function as follow :

```
getName("Warrior"); // to ask warrior for a warriors' name
getName("Mage"); // to ask for a mage's name.
```

You may also want to add to include the string library at the top of your file as not having it might also cause your code to simply not work. As well as making sure to properly store the name returned from your getName() function as follow :

```
string name = getName("Warrior");
```

Also , as others have said , maybe reading a bit more on how function receive and return values might be beneficial to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this. Try this updated code...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
string getName(string classType)
{
    string charName;
    cout << "What is your " << classType << "'s name?" << endl;
    cin >> charName;
    cout<<"your "<<classType<< "'s name is "<<charName<<endl;
    return charName;
}
int main()
{
    int Type; 
    string charName; 
    cout <<"Welcome to \"Orcs and Ogres\"" << endl;
    cout << "What class do you want to play?  " << endl;
    cout << "\tType 1 for Warrior class]" << endl;
    cout << "\tType 2 for Archer class ]" << endl;
    cout << "\tType 3 for Mage class   ]" << endl;
    cin >> Type;
    if(Type == 1)
    {
        cout << endl << "You are a warrior" << endl;
        string classType;
        classType = "warrior";
        getName("warrior");
    }
    else if(Type == 2)
    {
        cout << endl << "You are an archer" << endl;
        string classType;
        classType = "archer";
        getName("archer");
    }
   else if(Type == 3)
   {
        cout << endl << "You are a mage" << endl;
        string classType;
        classType = "mage";
        getName("mage");
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "UserError:  Number too high or too low";
    }
    return 0;
}
```